# Choosing a specific XML node using lxml in Python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I'm from a VBScript background and new to *lxml* with Python.

In VBScript, to choose a specific node, I would *simply* do something like:

`Set myNode = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/node1/node2/myNode")`.

What I have done with Python:

```
from lxml import etree
xmlDoc = etree.parse(fileName)
myNode =
```

**Question**: So what should be written in front of `myNode` to be able to select it?

Preferably *without using XPath*? Also taking *lxml* into account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
myNode = xmlDoc.find('node2/myNode')
```

The `etree.parse` function will return a root node (ie your `node1`), so you don't need to use an absolute path.

**Example**

```
content = '''
<root>
<div>
  <p>content 1</p>
</div>
</root>
'''

from lxml import etree

xmlDoc = etree.fromstring(content)
paragraph_element = xmlDoc.find('div/p')
print(paragraph_element)
```

**Output**

```
<Element p at 0x9f54bc8>
```

**Note:**
For my example I have used the function `etree.fromstring`. This is purely for demonstration purposes, so you can see a workable example using a string. The function `etree.parse` should generate the same result when working with files rather than strings.

**Aside:** Why not use XPath? It is extremely powerful!